# Does the C++ standard guarantee that when the return value of 'rdbuf' passed to the stream output operator, he conent of the buffer gets printed out

Tags: c++, iostream, stringstream, ostringstream

Consider the following code snippet:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "hello world!\n";
auto a = ss.rdbuf();
std::cout << a; // prints out "hello world!
```

The variable `a` is a pointer to an object of the type `std::stringbuf`. When it is passed to the stream output operator `<<`, with GCC9.4, the content of the stream buffer pointed by `a` gets printed out.

My question is: is this behavior just an accident from the way `std::stringbuf` is implemented in GCC, or does the language standard guarantee this will always work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `std::basic_stringbuf` is derived from a [std::basic_streambuf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf). Cppreference describes its use:

> The I/O stream objects `std::basic_istream` and `std::basic_ostream`, as well as all objects derived from them (`std::ofstream`, `std::stringstream`, etc), are implemented entirely in terms of `std::basic_streambuf`.

What does that mean? Well, let's take a look at the overload set for `std::basic_istream::operator<<` [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt):

> `basic_ostream& operator<<( std::basic_streambuf<CharT, Traits>* sb );`
> (10)

> Behaves as an `UnformattedOutputFunction`. After constructing and checking the sentry object, checks if `sb` is a null pointer. If it is, executes `setstate(badbit)` and exits. Otherwise, extracts characters from the input sequence controlled by `sb` and inserts them into `*this` until one of the following conditions are met:
>
> - end-of-file occurs on the input sequence;
> - inserting in the output sequence fails (in which case the character to be inserted is not extracted);
> - an exception occurs (in which case the exception is caught).
>
> If no characters were inserted, executes `setstate(failbit)`. If an exception was thrown while extracting, sets `failbit` and, if `failbit` is set in `exceptions()`, rethrows the exception.

So, yes, it's guaranteed by the standard that `std::cout << ss.rdbuf();` will have the effect you observed.

Comment: I have seen many case code like `std::cout << ss.str()`. Are they doing it wrong, introducing one extra copy for nothing?